# How to forward GRPC like a proxy?

Tags: proxy, grpc

I code a GRPC program, which uses GRPC Client to call Google APIs. Now because Google is blocked, so I have to use a different host when creating GRPC ClientChannel. I want to deploy a program on our cluster, that simply just forward the GRPC request to/back Google. Anyone knows if there exists any program to do that? It is not a reverse proxy, more like a tunnel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gRPC protocol is built on HTTP/2, so any HTTP/2 proxy would work.  You can try something like Envoy to do this.

Alternatively, you can write your own custom gRPC proxy using the gRPC generics API.